# Duplicate primary keys in MySQL table due to DoS attack

Tags: mysql, indexes

We have a MySQL database with duplicate primary key index entries as a result of a [DoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack. The duplicates cannot be found by selects on the ID (it will only show one row, not two), but if you select by a username or password, it will show the two rows. Is it possible to drop the primary key, remove the duplicate rows and then re-index the primary keys?

We found the duplicates existed after trying to repair the table.

Comment: I assume this is MyISAM key corruption? Please consider switching to InnoDB.

Comment: i think you're right - last night the web hosting company worked some magic on the db and the data was successfully repaired/duplicates removed. (i believe using cPanel) the table and db are indeed using MyISAM. i'll do some research on the benefits of InnoDB, thanks.

Comment: Consider switching to innodb, in careful consulation with the application developers, as part of a properly managed change which is fully tested. Be careful. It is a good idea though, in the broader sense.

Answer (score 0):

Some options off the top of my head:

- Create a new column with a unique constraint, drop the original column, and make the new one your PK.
- Alternatively, create a new table with a new PK, copy across everything except the duplicate column, drop the original table and rename the new.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a backup of the table and try it out?

Comment: the backups won't import due to the duplicate keys

Comment: If you make a mysqldump, you can edit the resulting SQL file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can delete records from table, the sql command below deletes the youngest duplicate record.

```
delete from table1 where ID in (select max(ID), username from table1 group by username)
```